# Is there a way to tell Excel to count data per date from a list?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm going to try to make this as specific as possible, but I apologize in advance if I'm not clear! I don't do much logic coding in Excel.

I'm trying to write a formula that will basically count the number of different role types of humpback whales (MC, G1, G2, etc.) seen per calendar day. It's really laborious to do it by hand, but I'm getting hung up on the formula.

The idea is basically to come up with a sum of the amount of times a role type was seen per day. So if the data looked like this:

```
Date,RoleType
3/1/19,MC
3/1/19,MC
3/1/19,MC
3/1/19,G1
3/2/19,MC
3/2/19,MC
```

I would want the results to come out as MC on 3/1/19 = 3, G1 on 3/1/19 = 1, MC on 3/2/19 = 2, etc. So I think it may be an AND statement situation, now that I think about it?

Ideally, I'd want to be able to select both the Date and RoleType columns in their entirety and then spit out the results in a table that would have the different role types on the X and the different dates on the Y.

I'm working with over a thousand sightings, so I'm reallyy trying to avoid doing this by hand. The expression I came up with so far is:

```
=IF(A3:A14=F$2, COUNTIF(B3:B14, "MC")
```

Where A3:A14 represents the date range being investigated, F$2 being the target date, B3:B14 is the list of role types being investigated, and "MC" is a (clunky, I know) manually entered designation of which role type is supposed to be counted.

Thanks so much for your time, everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done without formulas, using a pivot table that can be created in just a few clicks.

Make sure your data entry table is an Excel Table (Insert > Table). Then, click a cell in the table, then click Insert > Pivot Table. In the Pivot Field pane, drag Date to the rows area and RoleType to the columns area. Drag RoleType to the values area for a count.

Done.

When new data is added to the data entry table, refresh the PivotTable.

[image]

If you don't want to use a pivot table, you need to pre-populate the dates and the role types in the result table as in the following screenshot. Then use this formula in E2, copy across and down.

```
=COUNTIFS(Table2[Date],$D2,Table2[RoleType],E$1)
```

[image]

Comment: This is super useful, thank you!